# Draw line between all points on a layer based on parent field

Tags: qgis, point, line

I have a table that contains georeferenced points, a bunch of other information and a parent for each point.  So let's say the unique identifier is name in the table, each record also has a parent name.

Using QGIS I want to create a layer containing a line between each point and its parent and be able to change the line colour based on some of the other information in the record.  I think I can do the line colour easily but automatically generating the table with the lines is something I am hoping someone can help me with.

Comment: Could you add a little illustration of what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: link[https://www.infragistics.com/samples/WebImages/WPF/Controls/xamNetworkNode/wpf-data-visualization-network-node-bind-to-gml-key-features-image.jpg

Basically each point can have one parent and this draws a line to that parent.  There are 150,000 points

Answer (score 1):

In the plugin MMQGIS go `Create->Hub Lines`.  This joins lines between points and hubs (parents) as seems to be your use-case.  You may have to separate out the hubs and 'spoke-points' into two separate shapefiles.  See a more detailed description [here](http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/).

Comment: I am hoping this will work.  Just running now and has been going for about 45 minutes.  Any tips on how to speed it up?  The layers are shapefiles, but maybe some other format or some settings may help this go faster?

Comment: Still going about 8 hours later.  Hoping there is something that can speed up the processing.

Comment: How many points do you have?

Comment: I have 130,000 points